# Mesh networking under iOS

Tags: ios, networking, mesh-network

I have read that Apple added support for mesh networking in iOS 7.1 and now I'm pretty curious to see some working examples and/or tutorials on how to set these things up.

Has anyone any experience on that? Basically I would like to start letting 2 iOS devices communicate with each other via Wifi (without any router or AP) or Bluetooth.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I already found everything I need. On iOS it is called Multipeer Connectivity and here are is some documentation and a tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/exploring-the-multipeer-connectivity-framework-project-setup--mobile-23071

Edit:
There's also a good Video by Apple in their WWDC Video section: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/

And here's another useful link:
http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/

Comment: but how can we connect with android device.